# mySQL empty SELECT in SELECT shouldn't return null for the whole query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using a select in a select, like this :

```
SELECT id, 
(
    SELECT name FROM xxx WHERE xxx
) as y 
FROM xxx
```

But this y is null. And because of this, the whole query is returning null. I want this y to be a 0 if it is equal to null so not to change the result of the whole query which should return several tuples.

Here my full query :

```
        SELECT id, begin, end, location_id, out_location_id, lat, lng, out_lat, out_lng, LEFT(TIMEDIFF(end, begin), 5) as duration, 
        (
          SELECT LEFT(TIMEDIFF(end, begin), 5)
          FROM timeslots l
          WHERE user_id = '.$userId.'
          AND type = '.Timeslot::LUNCH.'
          AND parent_id = t.id 
        ) as lunch, 
        (
          SELECT LEFT(TIMEDIFF(end, begin), 5)
          FROM timeslots o
          WHERE user_id = '.$userId.'
          AND type = '.Timeslot::OVERTIME.'
          AND parent_id = t.id 
        ) as overtime
        FROM timeslots t
        WHERE user_id = '.$userId.'
        AND approved = 1
        AND type = '.Timeslot::DAY.'
        AND DATE(begin) >= "'.$startDay.'"
        AND DATE(end) <= "'.$endDay.'"
        ORDER BY begin
```

I tried COALESC(y, 0) and IFNULL(y, 0) but it doesn't work :/

thanks for you help

## UPDATE

I just noticed that when I remove the first subquery, it works ! So it means that the issues comes from this first subquery and not both of them. What's changing the result of the whole query is the line type = Timeslot::LUNCH (which is 2). But on the second subquery I have Timeslot::OVERTIME which is 3 so it's the same thing but it's working...

Comment: agree with @Gordon Linoff - a scalar subquery (appearing as a column in your `select` clause) *cannot* change the # of rows returned. It's like using a `delete` query to create new rows - it just won't happen. Can you make extra-extra-extra sure you're not changing something else when you "remove" the subquery/subqueries?

Comment: I updated the message

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Subqueries in the `SELECT` are called *scalar* subqueries.  These always return one column and at most one row.  If they return no rows, then the value is `NULL`.

They *do not* filter rows out of the result set.  It is as simple as that.

In other words, *nothing* you do in the two subqueries in the `SELECT` will affect the number of rows returned.  They only affect the value for that particular column.

Comment: This is what I always thought as well ! But when I remove these two 'subqueries' it returns me a bunch of rows, so it has to come from these two subqueries :/

Comment: I just noticed that when I remove the first subquery, it works ! So it means that the issues comes from this first subquery and not both of them. 
What's changing the result of the whole query is the line type = Timeslot::LUNCH (which is 2). But on the second subquery I have Timeslot::OVERTIME which is 3 so it's the same thing but it's working...